# Woocommerce Add Shop link to Cart & Checkout Breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I have Home > Cart and Home > Checkout in the breadcrumbs
I want to show them as Home > Shop > Cart and Home > Shop > Checkout .
without adding any other thing like category name and so on. 
any help, please?

Comment: which theme you are using? laos can you post a link also?

Comment: it is a custom theme. it was built by another developer.here is a link https://www.metabolic4you.ch/checkout/

Comment: Ok so currently you have home->cart and you need home->shop->cart?

Comment: yes, exactly Home > Shop > Cart and Home > Shop > Checkout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564512/wordpress-woocommerce-show-breadcrumbs-in-checkout-page